# error in JSON parsing with node

Tags: javascript

I need to make a query to MongoDB

```
db.orders.find({"createdAt":{$gte:ISODate("2017-03-05T20:58:45.654Z")}}).
```

I am using Node to make the query and the query is submitted by the user.
I am trying to use `JSON.parse(query)`, but it is not able to parse `"$"`. I searched for escape sequence, but its not working.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: This isn't JSON, you can't parse it as JSON and escaping wouldn't help you.

Comment: You appear to have shown us a bit of vaguely related code, but not the code that is actually having the problem. You've gone straight from passing an object to a `find()` method to `JSON.parse(query)` without ever defining `query`. You need a real [mcve]. If the problem is with `JSON.parse` then that should, ideally, be in the form of: 1. A variable to which is assigned a string literal with your JSON. 2. The JSON.parse statement. 3. A console.log to demonstrate the failed output.

Comment: the query has to be {"createdAt":{$gte:ISODate("2017-03-05T20:58:45.654Z")}}. As mongo uses object inside find as the query parameter. I am using JSON.parse to covert "query" into object